# find all possible sums in vector (R)

Tags: r, combinations

I have a vector of dollar values like this (vec):

```
[1]  460.08 3220.56 1506.20 1363.76 1838.00 1838.00 3684.94 2352.66 1606.02
[10] 1840.05  518.98 1603.53 1556.94  347.32  253.16   12.95 1828.81 1896.32
[19] 4962.60  426.33 3237.04 1601.40 2004.57  183.80 1570.75 3622.96  230.04
[28]  426.33 3237.04 1601.40 2004.57  183.80
```

If I have a charge that resulted from some sum of these numbers, how could I find it? For example, if the charge was 6747.81, then it must have resulted from 1506.20 + 3237.04 + 2004.57 (the 3rd, 29th and 31st vector elements). How could I solve for these vector elements given the sum?

I would imagine finding all possible sums is the answer then matching it to the vector elements that led to it.

I have played with using combn(vec, 3) to find all 3 but this doesn't quite quite give what I want.

Comment: Seems like a special case of the knapsack problem where you have to perfectly fill it. It is an NP-problem and you may just have to brute force it. Finding all combinations where you pick 3 values is not going to work; you need every combination that does not exceed your target value. IE, it is possible that you have 10 cheaper items or 2 expensive items.

Comment: Unless your problem is constrained to a small number of terms to be added together, this problem becomes really fun. Even with only a 32 number vector, you need to calculate 4.3 billion unique sums (32 pick 1 to 32).

Comment: `vec <- c(460.08, 3220.56, 1506.20, 1363.76, 1838.00 ,1838.00, 684.94, 2352.66, 1606.02, 1840.05, 518.98, 1603.53, 1556.94, 347.32, 253.16, 12.95, 1828.81, 1896.32, 4962.60, 426.33, 3237.04, 1601.40, 2004.57, 183.80, 1570.75, 3622.96, 230.04, 426.33, 3237.04, 1601.40, 2004.57, 183.80)`  My edit was thrice rejected as "changes too much in the original post", but here is the sample data in an easy-to-access format.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use `colSums` (or `apply`) after `combn` to get the sums.

```
set.seed(100)
# Generate fake data
vec <- rpois(10, 20)
# Get all combinations of 3 elements
combs <- combn(vec, 3)
# Find the resulting sums
out <- colSums(combs)
# Making up a value to search for
val <- vec[2]+vec[6]+vec[8]
# Find which combinations lead to that value
id <- which(out == val)
# Pull out those combinations
combs[,id]
```

Some output to show the results for this example

```
> vec
 [1] 17 12 23 20 21 17 21 18 22 22
> val
[1] 47
> combs[,id]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   17   12
[2,]   12   17
[3,]   18   18
```

Edit: Just saw that there isn't necessarily a restriction to use 3 items.  One could generalize this just by doing it for every possible sample size but I don't have time to do that right now.  It would also be fairly slow for even moderately sized problems.

Comment: @Vlo unless I'm mistaken, that won't make it convenient to find which numbers were used to give each sum, which is what's required.